# passing a value in anchor tag in django

Tags: django

So I'm in my profile page & want to edit my profile so I click edit button ,it takes me to a edit page where I have two buttons 'save'(inside form tag) & 'Exit'. Now if I click exit I want to get redirected to profile page of same person again. what input should I pass in below tag to do this?

```
(<a href="{% url 'profile'  %}"><button>Exit</button></a>
```

adding urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

path('',views.home, name='home'),
path('login/',views.loginp, name='login'),
path('profile/<str:ck>/',views.profile, name='profile'),
path('Edit_profile/<str:ck>/',views.Edit, name='Edit'),
path('logout/',views.logoutp, name='logout'),
path('register/',views.register, name='register'),

]
```

page where my button is located

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}

{{form.as_p}}

<input type ="submit" value="Save">

</form>

<a href="{% url 'profile' ?? %}"><button>Exit</button></a>
```

Comment: same url as you're using to see detailed information of Profile(Read mode) with user id

Comment: @HemalPatel - not always. If i logged in, i can take user id from session. Thats why we need to see an urls.py where  url name=profile defined

Comment: @MaximDanilov Sorry? I didn't understand. its a simple exit button to get back to the same profile in a reading mode which is in edit mode currently. so profile id with a detailed profile URL/Function will do a thing. nothing fancy or anything related to the session here i guess.

Comment: @HemalPatel - Try to google about best practices for user-profile-page or for Auth-part for application.

Answer (score 1):

For going back to particular profile you will need a url with profile/int:id and have to pass unique id of that particular profile in your url while calling exit.

Below is the sample you can do it where profile.id contains value of id of a profile.

```
<a href="{% url 'profile' id=profile.id %}"><button>Exit</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not agree with other answers.
If you on your profile page, it means you are logged in.

In this case - you don't need to define user.pk, and it is better for usability - i can simply save the link mydomain/profile instead of mydomain/profile/user_pk.

But you should define, how you get an user from Request.

```
class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs['pk'] = self.request.user.pk
        return super().get_object(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am shure - this is the better solution, than send `pk` in url.

LoginRequiredMixin- default django mixin for GCBV
DeteilView - django GCBV

More here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin

and

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

Comment: its not about letting user edit only his profile. he didnt mention other profiles shouldnt be editable by logged in user

Comment: @HemalPatel, you are wrong: in question "So I'm in my profile page & want to edit my profile". my answer is about "my profile" and best practices.